# Is there a way to see what property is a NewObject change referring to in Javers?

Tags: javers

When handling `onNewObject(NewObject change)` of the `ChangeProcessor` interface, is there a way to figure out where in the object graph (relative to the top objects compared) that new object is? The full path, not just relative to the immediate parent?

I have two properties of type Address somewhere lower in the graph, and if I print the change global ID, I get something like `...Address/22984` and `...Address/22985`, which doesn't tell me what each of those Address objects represent. I'd need to get the full path back up to the root object that shows in `javers.initial(rootObject)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JaVers dosn't record paths from the first object but for Value Objects, you can read the path recorded in `ValueObjectId`. It's the path from an owning Entity to a Value Object. For example:

`Employee/1#primaryAddress`